# Flash drive is inaccessible, only 8 MB of space and can't format

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

I have this problem when I was formatting my flash drive then I tested it with a "drive increaser" and it became inaccessible and unusable suddenly. I opened Disk Management and it had 8 MB of total space. I have experienced it before and the flash drives that were inaccessible and unusable were put to waste. I am lucky that I still have the files that were inside the flash drive. I can't delete the partition of the flash drive via Disk Management. Can someone please help me?
[This is a screenshot of My Computer, seeing that Removable Disk (E:) has no further details about it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8tgF.png)
[And this is a picture of Disk Management, pictured the partition details, 8 MB of total space.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cesla.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [HP USB Disk storage format tool](https://www.techspot.com/downloads/6582-hp-usb-disk-storage-format-tool.html). It should reformat the flash drive as it was.